# "no matching function for call to 'Vector::Vector'" error

Tags: c++

How to solve the error in the title?

**Vector class code:**

```
class Vector
{
public:
    uint32_t x;
    uint32_t y;
    Vector(uint32_t x, uint32_t y);
};

Vector::Vector(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}
```

Other class code:

```
class Test
{
    Test(Vector c1);
    Test(Vector c1, Vector c2);
    Vector c1, c2;
};

Test::Test(Vector c1) // << error here
{
    this->c1 = c1;
}

Test::Test(Vector c1, Vector c2) // << error here too
{
    this->c1 = c1;
    this->c2 = c2;
}
```

I tryed to rename arguments to not be the same as in class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Vector c1, c2;
```

This cannot work in your class Test, because this class (Vector) has no default constructor.

You can edit your Vector class:

```
class Vector
{
public:
    uint32_t x = 0;
    uint32_t y = 0;
    Vector(uint32_t x = 0, uint32_t y = 0);
};
```

Now there are default arguments so a statement like `Vector x;` is valid.

Comment: @Bee avoid function overloading if you can use default arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Your Vector class does not have a default constructor (one that takes no parameters), only a two parameter version.

The constructors for your Test class, as written, try to initialize the members c1 and c2 using their default construtors (and fail, because there are no default constructors they can use) and then assign new values to the c1 and c2 members *after* they have been already initialized.

You need to either provide a default constructor for Vector, or manually initialize the c1 and c2 members of Test:

```
Vector c1 = {0, 0}, c2 = {0, 0};
```

or

```
Test::Test(Vector c1)
    : c1(c1), c2(0, 0)
{}
```